# VBA "close" event for a single instance?

Tags: vba

I am writing a VBA Excel Add-in.
When the add-in is active, it defines some keyboard shortcuts with `Application.OnKey`. I would like to return these keyboard shortcuts to the default when the add-in closes, and I am using the `Auto_Close` method inside one of the add-in's modules for this.
However, I have come across a problem:
When the user opens multiple regular workbooks while my add-in is loaded, and closes just one of them, the `Auto_Close` on the add-in seems to trigger and turn off the keyboard shortcuts in the other windows.

How can I only trigger an `Auto_Close`-equivalent when the add-in is completely unloaded (other than completely exiting Excel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `Workbook_Open` and `Workbook_BeforeClose` events of the addin. I don't know why Auto_Close would behave as you describe, but I'm sure the two above will work.

Comment: I misspoke (and edited the question); Auto_Close isn't inside ThisWorkbook but within one of the other modules.  I'll try moving the logic to Workbook_BeforeClose though.